# Is this a normal output for : 'find / -user root -perm -4000 -print'?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5

```
# find / -user root -perm -4000 -print
find: /proc/21944/task/21944/fd/4: No such file or directory
find: /proc/21944/fd/4: No such file or directory
/sbin/unix_chkpwd
/sbin/pam_timestamp_check
/bin/ping
/bin/ping6
/bin/su
/bin/mount
/bin/umount
/lib/dbus-1/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
/usr/sbin/usernetctl
/usr/sbin/suexec
/usr/sbin/userhelper
/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/crontab
/usr/bin/chage
/usr/bin/sudoedit
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/bin/gpasswd
```

Comment: Yes. What of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's completely normal.  The `/proc` virtual filesystem provides an interface to the process and memory information on a system.  This allows tools like top(1) to use normal filesystem calls to examine processes and memory instead of doing non-portable mucking about in the system memory.  Information in this filesystem changes constantly as the state of the system changes.  In your example, file descriptor 4 for process 21944 was closed after the find command found it in the directory but before it could read it.

Since /proc is not a real filesystem, you usually want to [avoid it](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/don_t_let_find_drop) in any traversals of your filesystem.  Here's some more info on [using /proc in linux.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-proc.html)

Comment: You can use something like ``find / -path /proc -prune -or -user root -perm -4000 -print``.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the "No such file or directory" messages, in this case it means that those file descriptors for those processes were closed during the operation of the `find` command or the processes exited (which also means the file descriptors were closed). You can also get that message for broken symlinks.